# Using mysqli with Wordpress and future upgrades

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

All,
I'm trying to be good and get away from the mysql* php coding. I'm using wordpress for a new project and want to use the correct syntax for my database queries in my pages that I create. I want to use mysqli* but it looks like Wordpress uses mysql* commands when connecting with the database. For example, they have some code like this in the wp-include/wp-db.php file:

```
if ( !@mysql_select_db( $db, $dbh ) ) {
```

I did read I can adjust this file wp-includes/load.php to use my own database code which is called before the wpdb variable is set.

I also want this to be scalable, so I can upgrade to future versions of Wordpress. If I update these values and then need to upgrade Wordpress, I think these values will get overwritten and my site has potential to not work correctly.

I tried to use the $wpdb value in creating a query on one my pages from within Wordpress. I tried to do this following:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $info = $wpdb->get_results('Select * from vendor_types order by description ASC');
    foreach($info as $table) {
        echo $table->description;
    }
?>
```

When I do this, I get the correct output and it's what I would expect it to be. However, is this the best way to do this from a Wordpress perspective? I want to try and avoid using deprecated code in my applications?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's probably best to use Wordpress' database wrapper in this case. When/if they ever migrate away from mysql_*, their wrapper is likely to follow. (although I imagine migrating Wordpress would be a hellish job. I wonder what the status on that is...)

Comment: Well do you think you will move away from wordpress anytime soon? If you are then you will have to change every WPDB call in your scripts. Otherwise you can stick to mysqli.